# In C calloc quits the program

Tags: c, memory

So, I'm new to C. I'm trying to allocate memory for a 2D array. Whenever it gets to the calloc, it quits the program. I tried changing it to malloc, but that doesn't wok either. (Also, I'm Hungarian, so some of the text is hungarian sry)

Here's how I declared my matrix and how I give it to my function.

```
int** matrix = NULL;


matrixg(size, matrix);
```

Here's the part in the function which I think is relevant:

```
void matrixg(int* size,int** matrix2){

    //Mátrix mérete
    int k = 0;
    char szamseged[11];
    printf("How big should the matrix be? Under no cicumstance, type 0. (at least 1, maximum 20):\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(szamseged, 10, stdin);
    int meret = atoi(szamseged);
    while(meret == 0){
        if(k == 1){
            printf("I can do this all day.\n");
        }
        printf("Try again dummy!\n");
        getchar();
        fgets(szamseged, 10, stdin);
        meret = atoi(szamseged);
        k++;
    }
    *size = meret;

    *matrix2 = calloc((*size), sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*size); i++) {
        printf("na ez jó.");
        matrix2[i] = calloc((*size), sizeof(int));
    }
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: You call `calloc` but never check the return value to ensure that it actually succeeded. If it didn't, your code will have undefined behavior.

Comment: Please take better notice of compiler warnings.

Comment: If `matrix2` is NULL, then `*matrix2 = ...` is an error.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mixup in your levels of indirection.  Supposing it succeeds, this ...

> ```
> *matrix2 = calloc((*size), sizeof(int*));
> ```

... sets `*matrix2`, a.k.a. `matrix2[0]`, to point to an allocated block large enough for `*size` objects of type `int *`.  This relies on `*matrix2` designating an existing object of type `int *`, which could be your problem.  But even if that's ok,

1. Inside your loop, you overwrite `matrix2[0]` with a different pointer, thus leaking the original allocation, and
2. Nothing in the code presented ensures that `matrix[1]` or *any* of the `matrix[i]` designate valid objects.

Most likely, you want something more like this:

```
// Note _triple_ pointer, because you want (I assume) to assign a value to
// a double pointer belonging to the caller:
void matrixg(int* size,int*** matrix2){
    // ...

    *size = meret;

    int **temp = calloc((*size), sizeof(*temp));
    // alternatively:
    // int **temp = calloc((*size), sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*size); i++) {
        printf("na ez jó.");
        temp[i] = calloc((*size), sizeof(*temp[i]));
        // alternatively:
        // temp[i] = calloc((*size), sizeof(int));
    }

    *matrix2 = temp;

    // ...
}
```

You would call it like so:

```
    int size;
    int **matrix;
    matrixg(&size, &matrix);
```

For clarity, that does omit any checking for allocation success.  For robustness, however, you absolutely should verify that each allocation succeeds, and take appropriate action -- maybe a diagnostic message and clean shutdown -- if any of them fail.